# Java - Copy folder from windows network path

Tags: java, windows, file, smb

I am trying to copy the folder from the windows network share folder which protected by username and password

```
String url = "smb://40.123.xx.xx/sharefolder/"; 
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "username", "pas.");
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
if(dir.exists()) {
File[] directories = new File("\\40.123.xx.xx\\sharefolder")
                .listFiles(file -> file.isDirectory() && file.getName().matches("[0-9]{6}"));

for (File getDirectory : directories) {
Path folder = Paths.get(getDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(folder, BasicFileAttributes.class);
//          System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
                System.out.println("creationDate : " + sdf.format(attr.creationTime().toMillis()));
    try {
//      FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(new File(getDirectory.getAbsolutePath()),new File("F:\\localFolder"));
                    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
    }
}
```

But the File[] directories return null instead of return all folders path.

How do I access network folder and copy the files to local path.

Answer (score 1):

Your UNC pathname has only one escaped backslash at the beginning so is not valid UNC path for the remote filesystem, so you are scanning `\40.123.xx.xx\sharefolder` when it should be scanning `\\40.123.xx.xx\sharefolder`:

```
System.out.println(new File("\\40.123.xx.xx\\sharefolder"))
\40.123.xx.xx\sharefolder        (WRONG)

System.out.println(new File("\\\\40.123.xx.xx\\sharefolder"))
\\40.123.xx.xx\sharefolder       (CORRECT)
```